# Compact set contained in the interior of another compact set

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Does the property "every compact set is contained in the interior of some compact set" has a special widely known name? Is it related to paracompactness?

Comment: In a locally compact space the property just holds, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property is equivalent to “every point has a compact neighborhood”, so it is just the weak formulation of local compactness, which is equivalent to local compactness in Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: I see, of course, trivially. (Bad question.) Thanks for the hint. Let $K \subseteq X$ be compact. For $x \in K$ let $K_x$ be a compact neighborhood. Then $\bigcup_{x \in K} \textrm{int}(K_x)$ is an open cover of $K$. Now $K$ is covered already by finitely many $\textrm{K}_{x_i}$, $i = 1, \dots, n$ which implies $K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n \textrm{int}(K_{x_i}) \subseteq \textrm{int}(\bigcup_{i=1}^n K_{x_i}) = \textrm{int}(K')$ and $K' := \bigcup_{i=1}^n K_{x_i}$ is compact.